# how to convert factor column into date in data frame in r

Tags: r, date, dataframe, type-conversion, r-factor

I have a data frame in r with the following structure:

```
TERMINAL_ID ACTION_DATE ACC_AMOUNT
1009162   02-JAN-18      14.30
1009162   02-JAN-18      21.45
```

and the class for 'action_date' is factor and I would to convert it to date.
I tried this code but no success

```
dataf <- as.Date(as.character(data$ACTION_DATE),
                                format = "%d-%y-%Y")
fdate=as.POSIXlt(data$ACTION_DATE, "%d-%b-%y")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.Date('02-JAN-18', format = '%d-%B-%y')

[1] "2018-01-02"
```

Comment: or by using lubridate

Comment: how did you apply the code? It shouldn't give NA

@MarBlo your solution is also valid, could you confirm that this solution does not produce NA?

Comment: @astrofunkswag: the answer as I gave it, does not create NA's. If you have a look at how x85ms16 used the answer, you'll see that there are NA's made, of course,, if the input data is not formatted right.

Answer (score 2):

or by using lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
dmy("02-Jan-17")
```

this turns your character which holds the date in d(ays)m(onth)y(ear) into a Date format.

Answer (score 1):

I have created vector `x` with date format you mentioned. Using the `lubridate` package, the solution was pretty straight forward.

```r
x<- as.factor(c("02-JAN-18", "03-JAN-19", NA, "abc"))
lubridate::dmy(x)
#> Warning: 1 failed to parse.
#> [1] "2018-01-02" "2019-01-03" NA           NA
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>